# WCF Best Practice For WebMessageBodyStyle

Tags: web-services, wcf

I have several questions regarding to wcf `WebMessageBodyStyle` best practice:

1. What is the diffrence between bare and wrapped?
2. Does bare and wrapped effects `Json` or just the `xml` format?
3. What `WebMessageBodyStyle` will be more efficent in a narraow bandwidth network?
4. What is the best practice binding to a cellular network?

Thanks.